# could anyone give me help on ground-truth data

Tags: data-mining

I recently came to a term in one of my email communicatons with my supervisor.Since I am beinging doing a data-mining project on facebook user profile,and he said I should being collecting groud-truth data.

I am very new to this term and I searched online for it,but found very few results about it in data-mining sense.

Could anyone give me an example of what this groud-truth data is in a data-mining task pleae?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ground-truth is data annotated (generally by human) known to be sure at 100%.
It's used to train algorithm since it's what you expect the algorithm to give you.